# nginx 404 not found if URL contains "star"

Tags: unix, nginx

Weird problem: If the URL contains the word "star", the result is a 404. It does only happen with this word.

**Working:**
http://example.com/some/another/url

**Not working:**
http://example.com/some/url/with/**star**

The virtual host config is not the problem as it appears on all server blocks, even in the default one.

The error does not appear in the access.log!

Anyone else with nginx 1.9.14 can reproduce this strange problem?

Comment: Glad to hear you found the source of the issue. In the future, providing the relevant part of the configuration file would help us see what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason was a copy & pasted line that should cache static files:
`~*.(ogg|ogv|svg|tar…)`

Since "star" is ending with `tar` (like the `.tar` archive) the rule fired because there is a missing backslash. It must be

`location ~*\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svg|tar)`

Thanks to nginx mailing group!